# Stack overflow error when reading jpeg image using Cimg library

Tags: c, image, stack-overflow, cimg

I'm getting stack overflow error when I'm trying to read jpg file using `Cimg` library while other format bmp is working file .

How can i resolve it?

```
    #include"CImg.h"
    #include<stdio.h>
    using namespace cimg_library;
    int main()
    {
            CImg<unsigned char> src("d:\\sidimg.jpg");
            int width = src.width();
            int height = src.height();
            unsigned char* ptr = src.data(0,0);
            int count=0;
              while(count!= width*height)
                {

                   printf("%d",*ptr);
                   ptr++;
                   count++;
                }
   }
```

Comment: Looks like it should be while count < width*height since images aren't 0 indexed I don't think (starts at pixel 1)

Comment: there is no problem with while loop, i tested this program with bmp files working fine. problem is with jpg image

Comment: The stack overflow occurs when you overright your buffer (or stack).  Maybe you should try and flush stdout because maybe printf's are building up and causing it to overflow.  Other than that, it looks fine, and hsouldn't be a problem, since stdout should auto flush itself when its full.

Comment: same error with pixel 1

Comment: You shouldn't exit when its !=, its bad convention.  You should bounds it more tightly (rather than at one finite point).  So use <

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but you have to have [convert.exe](http://www.thebest3d.com/dogwaffle/patches/im/convert.zip) from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package in the same directory as where the program is executing in order to read/write jpeg images.