# cimg display() nothing, but debug messages are right

Tags: c++, c, g++, mingw, cimg

Env: win7 mingw g++ 4.6.2

The code is very simple.

```
CImg<int> img("xxx.jpg");
img.display();
```

I use `g++ -o xxxx xxxx.cpp -lgdi32` to compile the program.

The debug messages show the image was read correctly. I mean the values of pixels. But the display window shows nothing.

PS: when I use vs2012, the `display()` works fine.

Anyone knows why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
[Stack overflow error when reading jpeg image using Cimg library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864709/stack-overflow-error-when-reading-jpeg-image-uisng-cimg-library)

See also examples/use_jpeg_buffer.cpp in CImg examples.